# Finding out who set errno

Tags: c

Is there a way to find out in which function/file/line set the current errno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, <strike>it's just a global static int (no magic in it)</strike> (see comment below).

You're supposed to check after each function that could set it when it returns an error.

Comment: Actually it's not necessarily a global `int`; it may be a macro that expands to an rvalue in thread-local storage.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about that enough.

Comment: +1 for the rest of the answer, though. The "when it returns an error" part is crucial: if the function returns normally, `errno` may still be set to a non-zero value due to a previous function.

Comment: ... and then comes `strtod` where you actually need to reset it before calling the function... `errno` is fun :-)

Comment: Yep, `errno` is a major design flaw in the C library. The Unix kernel actually uses negative returns for errors in all implementations that I know; the `syscall` function then translates this elegant approach to error handling to the kludge that is `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not programmatically.

Just a thought: if this is a debugging issue, it might be possible to set a memory breakpoint on the address where the value of `errno` is stored and have it break when the memory is written to. The call stack would then tell you who did it.